# Infragistics 12.120121.2059 version with bootstrap 3.2 in MVC 4 giving error while load infragistics grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, infragistics

How can i use Infragistics 12.120121.2059 version with bootstrap 3.2. In bootstrap i am using jquery 1.9.1.min.js file which is not supported by infragistics. Showing the following error in infragistics.ui.grid.framework.js file .  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: The remote request to fetch data has failed:  (parsererror) Invalid character"

Answer (score 0):

i asked to the community of Infragistics regarding this question they replied me that they support Infragistics and Bootstrap to work together but not for this version. To use the both one has to upgrade the version from 12.1  to at least 13.1 or can use latest 15.1 version.

Please refer this link for further understanding.[click here](http://infragistics.com/community/forums/p/97410/480573.aspx#480573)